# Is there a way to split read/write queries in Quartz Scheduler to use mysql master slave replication?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, quartz-scheduler, database-replication

I am using Quartz scheduler in my application and I am also using master-slave replication for my other DB queries. I want to use the master-slave replication for Quartz scheduler as well hence I want to know if there is a way I can make the changes to split write/read queries which quartz makes to master/slave respectively?

I tried changing the "quartz.properties" but then all the calls going to the master node only

```
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.URL=jdbc:mysql:replication://localhost:3306,localhost:3307/quartz?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.user=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.password=root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.maxConnections=10
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.validationQuery=select 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple datasources in quartz.properties.

`quartzDS` is a specific datasource. You can add more with different names by tagging the properties with the name you want (like `org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDSTheSecond`).

See: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigDataSources

You then can get a [connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501414/getting-database-connection-using-quartz) using `DBConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection("quartzDSTheSecond")`;

Comment: This is a way to create multiple datasources but how does quartz splits the read/write db queries. I am using the quartz's apis to schedule the jobs which means that I don't have control over which call goes to master and which goes to slave in replication. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I misunderstood your question and thought you were refering to connections while executing a job. Sorry, but I don't know how to tell quartz to use different sources when managing its jobstore. Maybe you want to have a look at the JobStoreCMT (http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreCMT), it may provide the functionality you need, but I doubt it.